# R: Calculate distance between consecutive points per group and group them

Tags: r

i am having hard time with this one...So i am trying to find points per group that are close to each other and furthermore group them. Let me explain You on base of the example data below:

```
  Group    X   Y  Z
1   110 3762 431 10
2   112 4950 880 10
3   113 5062 873 20
4   113 5225 874 30
5   113 5262 875 10
6   113 5300 874 20

structure(list(Group = c(110, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113), X = c(3762, 
4950, 5062, 5225, 5262, 5300), Y = c(431, 880, 873, 874, 875, 
874), Z = c(10, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

As we can see we have grouping column *Group*, *X* & *Y* Columns are our coordinates and *Z* Column should be further summarised when points are defined as "Close" (Euclidean distance < 100).

**What i have tried:**

I have calculated sucesfully Euclidean distance between points using this function:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(test)) {
  if(i > 1 && test$Group[i] == test$Group[i-1]) {
    test$Distance[i] <- sqrt(((test$X[i] - test$X[i-1]) ^ 2) + ((test$Y[i] - test$Y[i-1]) ^ 2))
  } else {
    test$Distance[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

**Which gives me this:**

```
   Group    X   Y  Z  Distance
1   110 3762 431 10        NA
2   112 4950 880 10        NA
3   113 5062 873 20        NA
4   113 5225 874 30 163.00307
5   113 5262 875 10  37.01351
6   113 5300 874 20  38.01316
```

And here everything complicates as there are NA´s for the first row for each Group etc....

**What i wanna achieve:**

I would like to find points per goup that their distance is not greater then **100** (*Distance* < 100), and on base of that summarise it (simple sum of *Z* column). So manually done:

```
 Group    Z  Grouped
1   110  10   no     
2   112  10   no     
3   113  20   no     
4   113  60   yes
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to merge points by adding their "Z" score (within groups) when they are closer than a specified threshold? Right now, your results will depend on the order your points are in, I think, is this what you want?

Comment: Yes exactly thats what i Need (and extra column which says that Points have been grouped)

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit tricky because the ordering might affect the result, do you have an algorithm in mind for the ordering? E.g. in this example, what if point 5 was close to point 3 ?

Comment: Well You can in this case assume that the row number corresponds to order (or You can create new column just with increasing number). The original data comes from machine which performs measurement through length (X Column) and width (Y Column) of the rod --> it moves through length of the rod

Comment: But when i think about it You might be right and it makes it even more complicated!

Comment: Well usually once you've figured out your algorithm the code writes itself :)

Comment: Well i have tried myself but as you can see i got stuck with this Problem...I just want to summarise Points that are Close to each other on a plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a little use case that can get you started. It is a base approach using a for loop and aggregation based on vector of columns to which you could apply a paired vector of functions by which to aggregate.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Group    X   Y  Z  Distance
1   110 3762 431 10        NA
2   112 4950 880 10        NA
3   113 5062 873 20        NA
4   113 5225 874 30 163.00307
5   113 5262 875 10  37.01351
6   113 5300 874 20  38.01316
7   114 5300 874 30  NA
8   114 5300 874 20  38.01316", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

aggregateIt <- function(df = data, #data.frame
                        returnRaw = F, #to get the raw unaggregted df (only first case from column `grouped` by `subgroup` usable in this application)
                        colsToAgg = c("Z1", "Z2", "Z3"), #cols to aggregate
                        how = c("sum", "sum", "max")) #how to aggregate the columns, `Z1` by sum, `Z2` by sum and `Z3` by max
  {
  count <- 1L
  result <- vector("integer", nrow(df))
  grouped <- vector("character", nrow(df))
  for(i in seq_len(length(result)-1L)){
    if(df$Group[i] != df$Group[i+1L]) {
      result[i] <- count
      grouped[i] <- "no"
      count <- count + 1L
      if((i+1L) == length(result)) {
        result[i+1L] <- count
        grouped[i+1L] <- "no"
      }
    } else {
        if(df$Distance[i+1L] > 100L) {
          result[i] <- count
          grouped[i] <- "no"
          count <- count + 1L
          if((i+1L) == length(result)) {
            result[i+1L] <- count
            grouped[i+1L] <- "no"
          }
        } else {
          result[i] <- count
          grouped[i] <- "yes"
          if((i+1L) == length(result)) {
            result[i+1L] <- count
            grouped[i+1L] <- "yes"
          }
        }
    }
  }
  df <- within(df, {subgroup <- result; grouped <- grouped})
  if(returnRaw) return(df)
  A <- Reduce(function(a, b) merge(a, b, by = "subgroup"), 
         lapply(seq_along(how), function(x) aggregate(.~subgroup, df[, c(colsToAgg[x], "subgroup")], how[x])))
  B <- df[!duplicated(df$subgroup, fromLast = F), c("Group", "subgroup", "grouped")]
  out <- merge(A, B, by = "subgroup")
  return(out[, c("Group", colsToAgg, "grouped")])
}

aggregateIt(df = df, colsToAgg = "Z", how = "sum")
#  Group  Z grouped
#1   110 10      no
#2   112 10      no
#3   113 20      no
#4   113 60     yes
#5   114 50     yes
```

Not claiming this is most efficient solution but it points out the solution. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

That was difficult. I'm not sure I have figured it out completely.

```
#get data and libraries

library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "
Group    X   Y  Z  Distance
1   110 3762 431 10        NA
2   112 4950 880 10        NA
3   113 5062 873 20        NA
4   113 5225 874 30 163.00307
5   113 5262 875 10  37.01351
6   113 5300 874 20  38.01316", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  do(melt(outer(.$Distance, .$Distance, `-`))) %>%
  filter(between(value, -100, 0) | between(value, 0, 100)) %>% 
  distinct(Var1) %>%
  mutate(grouped = 1) %>%
  rename(row = Var1) -> rows

  df %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  left_join(rows, by = c("row", "Group")) %>%
    mutate(grouped = ifelse(is.na(grouped), "no", "yes")) %>%
    group_by(Group, grouped) %>%
    mutate(Z = ifelse(!is.na(grouped), sum(Z), Z)) %>%
    distinct(Group, Z, grouped)


# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Group, grouped [4]
  Group     Z grouped
  <int> <int> <chr>  
1   110    10 no     
2   112    10 no     
3   113    20 no     
4   113    60 yes
```

Hope it's what you were looking for, if not maybe it gave you some new ideas.

**UPDATE**: And now what I hope will really help you:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(int1 = lead(Distance) < 100 | Distance < 100,
         int1 = replace(int1, is.na(int1), FALSE),
         int2 = rleid(int1),
         int2 = replace(int2, !int1 | is.na(int1), NA)) -> df2

  df2 %>%
  filter(int1) %>% 
    group_by(Group, int2) %>%
    summarise(Z = sum(Z),
              Grouped = "yes") %>% 
    select(Group, Z, Grouped) %>%
    bind_rows(df2 %>%
                filter(!int1) %>%
                mutate(Grouped = "no") %>%
                select(Group, Z, Grouped)) %>%
    arrange(Group)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Group [3]
  Group     Z Grouped
  <int> <int> <chr>  
1   110    10 no     
2   112    10 no     
3   113    60 yes    
4   113    20 no
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer! It is almost working well...I have just spotted one Problem and it has to do with `outer` function --> saying closely FUN Argument... Using `-` is not correct as the distances are already calculated between consecutive rows per group

Comment: you are correct, I was solving my own imaginary problem.  And I am already thinking of another solution. Maybe I'll come to it soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, i really appreciate it!